# Switch contact ratings

Tags: datasheet, safety, button, maximum-ratings

Inside an enclosure, a device is powered by an SMPS as follows:

[image]

The device operates under 12 VDC and sinks 6 A from the SMPS. The SMPS is wired to AC by an IEC inlet. Now I want to install an emergency stop switch either at point X or Y above. Here are the contact ratings of [this](https://docs.rs-online.com/ba0b/0900766b81462086.pdf) button:

[image]

My questions are:

1. Does that mean this switch should not be installed at point Y since it passes 6 A at 12 VDC? What should be the max current rating at 12 VDC for this button?
2. What is meant by Monitor Contact? Can you give an example situation where it is used?

Comment: What is "the device?"  Generally, E-Stops are wired into the *control* section of the device, such that pressing the E-Stop (or failure of the E-Stop wiring) causes the device to instantly halt.  This is preferred over simply interrupting the power because that it is not a *controlled stop* but *uncontrolled*.  E-Stops generally are not used for power-switching, which is why they don't come in "large" sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Correct. It is clear the switch is only rated for 2A at DC for a resistive load. We do not know if your ‘device’ is resistive or reactive.
2. The monitor contact can be used to activate an indicator or notify the control system that the emergency stop switch has been activated.

Possible solutions are to select a more suitable switch or add a relay to switch the load.